# If statement in for loop

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of integer arrayslists and an arraylist of names. I'd like to add a certain number to one of those integer arraylists when it corresponds with a particular name and add a 0 to every other arraylist. I think that what I have should work, but it simply adds a 0 to everything and ignores the special case when the name is right. "Rating" is an integer, and "user" is a string. "Names" is an arraylist of strings. The language is Java.

```
for(int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++)
            {   

                if (names.get(i)==user)

                    allratings.get(i).add(rating);

                if (names.get(i)!=user) 

                    allratings.get(i).add(0);
            }
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? When I insert a print line, I find that my names arraylist and my allratings arraylist are perfectly matched up. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1. What language? 2. What type is `names`? 3. What type is `user`? Also, why have two if statements? The second one is just an `else` to the first clause.

Comment: This is java. Names is an arraylist of strings, user is a string. I'll add this info. And yes, it was else but that wasn't working, so I switched it thinking that might be it.

Comment: The inside of the for loop can be done in one line: `allratings.get(i).add(user.equals(names.get(i)) ? rating : 0);` or, split the `allratings.get(i)` into one line and the `add` into the other. Your code as it stands has lots of duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.equals()` when comparing Strings in Java:

```
if (user.equals(names.get(i)))
```

Comparing Strings in Java with `==` will compare references, which might not be what you want. It seems that the references are different, even though they hold the same string. This is why your condition is always returning false. You want to compare the actual value of the string. This is done with `.equals()`.

Answer (score 8):

User is a string, and in Java `==` isn't for use in string comparisons, as it's comparing the reference (or pointer if you prefer) and not the text content of the string.  use:

```
if (names.get(i).equals(user))
```

Comment: @WAMoz56 (Nice username) accept Oleksi's answer, as he was first, according to SO's order by `oldest`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `==` compares references. Often, due to the string literal pool maintained by Java, if you compare references, the might return `true`. If you create a `String s = "test"` and another `String s2 = "test"`, they both will point to the same reference because of the string pool (this is a Java optimization) and hence return `true`. Do not do this, though. Be safe and use `.equals()`!

Answer (score 1):

Comparing strings like this doesn't work in Java; because they point to different locations in memory. To fix this, try to `intern()` them first (which will make them point to the same data in memory), or use the method `equals()` like:

```
string1.equals(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the equality test is failing (which is why != is succeeding for each iteration). 
If the values of 'names.get(i)' and 'user' appear to be the same, perhaps the types are different; does one of those values require a CAST to a different type?

Comment: Perhaps, names is an arraylist of strings, and user is a string. I'll try a cast though.

Comment: Check the basics: toss in a print (or look in the debugger, as suggested below) to make sure that the values match. Also, make sure that there's not any extra whitespace on either of the strings that could be causing an inequality